# PropertyChangedEventHandler is null

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have the following class which will be the binding source:

```
public class Timeline : Canvas, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

  public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeTextBindingPropProperty;
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
  }

  public double TimeTextBindingProp
  {
    get { return (double)GetValue(TimeTextBindingPropProperty); }
    set 
    {
      SetValue(TimeTextBindingPropProperty, value);
      OnPropertyChanged("TimeTextBindingProp");
    }
  }

  static Timeline()
  {
    TimeTextBindingPropProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TimeTextBindingProp", typeof(double), typeof(Timeline));
  }
}
```

Then I set the binding between a textbox's `Text` property and `timeline's TimeTextBindingProp` property at my main window:

```
private void InitTextBinding()
{
  timeTextBinding = new Binding();
  timeTextBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
  timeTextBinding.Source = timeline;
  timeTextBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("TimeTextBindingProp");
  timeTextBinding.Converter = new TimeTextConverter();

  BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.timeTextBox, TextBox.TextProperty, timeTextBinding);
}
```

`PropertyChanged` handler of `timeline` remains null even after binding is set and `timeline` is rendered. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**:

I declare timeTextBox and timeline in xaml as follows:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBox Name="timeTextBox" Margin="0,0,20,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Height="20" 
                            FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" BorderBrush="White" Background="White"/>

    <Button Name="playButton" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" Click="PlayButton_Click" Margin="0,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    Play
    </Button>

    <Button Name="stopButton" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" Click="StopButton_Click" Margin="0,0,20,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    Stop
    </Button>

    <Slider Name="controlSlider" Height="Auto" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False">
      <Slider.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textStyleTextBlock}">Time Slider</TextBlock>
      </Slider.ToolTip>
    </Slider>
</StackPanel>

<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" Margin="0,0,10,20" Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Focusable="False"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <StackPanel>
    <UI:FittingCanvas x:Name="containerCanvas">
      <timelinePanel:Timeline x:Name="timeline" TimeCursorEnabled="True" TimeMode="Minutes"  Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.ZIndex="0" Visibility="Hidden"
                                                CursorAnimBoundaryChanged="Timeline_CursorAnimBoundaryChanged" AnimationCompleted="Timeline_AnimationCompleted"/>
    </UI:FittingCanvas>

    <Canvas x:Name="waveFormCanvas" Height="80" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
  </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Why is your bindingmode oneway? With textboxes it should be twoway.

Comment: @slfan Could be want to support copy.  Cannot copy a textblock.

Comment: It is just for display not for edit

Comment: Then TextBlock is faster

Comment: Any messages in the Output Window? (Binding and Conversion errors show up only there)

Comment: @HenkHolterman no nothing at all.

Comment: Your code works just fine in a test project here. Could you post your XAML as well? At least the bits where you declare `timeline` and `timeTextBox`?

Comment: @Sphinxxx I posted the code. By the way this is not the whole Timeline class. I just posted the code relevant to the binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your code update `timeTextBox.Text` any other way than setting the `timeTextBinding`? Maybe you set timeTextBox.Text to some value directly in the code-behind, or you have some other binding hooked up to it?

Because timeTextBinding is only *OneWay*, such a change can't be written back to `TimeTextBindingProp`, and the binding will simply be overwritten and deleted (without any warning), and `timeline.PropertyChanged` will be reset to `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I set the timeTextBox.text to some string after binding is set and this was the cause of problem. After I removed this, binding started working. Does this mean that after binding is set nothing should set the property value otherwise binding would be canceled? This is weird to me if it is the case. Binding should ignore the set or immeadiately overwrite the set with the binding value according to my logic. Is this because binding has lower precedence than local modification? Thanks for the answer again as it resolved the issue.

Comment: Yep, on _OneWay_ bindings that's just how it works. If you want to change the value manually, you should set `TimeTextBindingProp` instead of `timeTextBox.Text` to push the value "the right way" through the binding system. On _TwoWay_ bindings, you can change either property manually, and the other will change accordingly (as expected).